# How do I configure php/apache2 to display exceptions but not stack traces?

Tags: php, exception, configuration, apache2

What error reporting combination is required to display exceptions but not full stack traces?

ie:

```
throw new Exception("This is an exception");
```

Show "This is an exception" but not the full trace that follows?

Comment: you'll need to catch it and show only what you want `e.getMessage()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_exception_handler` to create your own exception handler which only Shows the error message

For example:

```
set_exception_handler(
    function($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        //exit(); dont have to be called
    }
);
```